# how to access a marker in an google maps event handler?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
for(; j<cos[i].length; j++) {
    var markerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(cos[i][j].lat, cos[i][j].lng);

    // Place a draggable marker on the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerLatLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Drag me!"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,  'rightclick',  function(mouseEvent) { 
        alert(marker.getPosition().lat());
    });
}
```

The page is alerting the position of the last marker in the list or the lastly created marker. The goal is to display position of each individual marker when right click on that marker is clicked but right clicking is currently only displaying the position of the last marker. Why is the function for event handler only seeing the last marker?

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: try to add you markers within your for loop and set your eventlistiner outside of the for loop where you create your markers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **this** keyword:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,  'rightclick',  function() { 
    alert(this.getPosition().lat());
});
```

Comment: thanks this did it. how to know what this points to inside a event handler?

Comment: If there is a documentation, you can try to find this information there. Otherwise you can try to figure it out with debugger in your browser.